# how to write unit tests for REST web services developed using apache-cxf with spring without using Maven

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, cxf, jax-rs, embedded-jetty

I have developed a REST web application using apache cxf library. I am able to access them using a browser and test. I want to write unit tests for the services.

I tried testing it using embedded Jetty server with cxf. 
After starting the Jetty server, I am getting a proxy using WebClient API of cxf. The relevant code is

`WebClient client = WebClient.create(ENDPOINT_ADDRESS);

 client.accept("text/xml");

client.path("/studyservice/topimstudydetails");

client.replaceQuery("pnlId=3&lclId=30&indId=442&maxImStudies=99&rName=DEV");
TopIMStudyDetailsResponse resp = client.get(TopIMStudyDetailsResponse.class);
assertEquals(resp.getStatus().getReturnCode(),0);`

The call to the service is successful as I can see the logs, but I'm get a null pointer where the service is trying to make a dao call. The dao is declared as a dependency for the service. How can we get a proxy with all the dependencies injected ?

Answer (score 1):

May be you'll find the following posts helpful:

- http://tarlogonjava.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/running-integration-test-using-with.html
- http://tarlogonjava.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/running-integration-tests-using-with.html

The second post is about replacing the data source with a special in-memory data source for tests.

Comment: Thanks Tarlog. But I am looking for something specific to cxf.